# Navigate Google Search purely with keyboard - WITHOUT Google Instant

Tags: google-search

One of the very useful features of Google Instant ([just dropped by Google](http://searchengineland.com/google-dropped-google-instant-search-279674)) was that I could "control" the search *purely with keyboard* using:

- tab to focus search results
- arrows to cycle through the results
- enter to go to the selected result
- other keys to get back to the search box

Is there any way of doing this now that Google Instant is dead?

Comment: I have same issue. Tab navigation does not work anymore.

Comment: For me, it does not work on Google Chrome anymore but it still works on Safari. Is it the same for you? Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Hey Matthew, I don't have Safari, so not sure. Previously it was working everywhere, but it looks like it was thanks to Google Instant. Perhaps Safari has some special browser support for Google search?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I created a very simple [open source extension](https://github.com/infokiller/google-search-navigator) to fix this and make keyboard shortcuts configurable.

You can install it from the Chrome Webstore:
 [Google Search Navigator](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-search-navigator/cohamjploocgoejdfanacfgkhjkhdkek).

Hope you find it useful, but in any case- feedback is welcome!

Comment: Thanks, works awesome! Still, I invite other ideas as I use both Firefox and Chrome, and it would be nice to find something which in any browser :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is also a Chrome Extension called RESULTER, which does not solve the exact problem described in the question, but provides good search results navigation anyway.

You can download it from Web Store: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/resulter-shortcuts-for-se/chojfhfgbdaeokblbdeahgbijodikdpk