# Navigate Google search results with keyboard

Tags: google-search, keyboard-shortcuts

It takes way too many `tab` presses to reach to the search results. Long back, Google had a nice keyboard navigation for search results (Google Instant). Why did Google turn the keyboard navigation off for search? Google supports more complex keyboard shortcuts in Gmail for example.

I have multiple chrome profiles and use other browsers as well. So installing extension is a pain. How do most power users navigate the search results, everyone installing the extension?

Reference:

- [Navigate Google Search purely with keyboard - WITHOUT Google Instant](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/108098/navigate-google-search-purely-with-keyboard-without-google-instant)